# Evaluate $\int \frac{\arctan(\sin2x)}{\cos^2x}\ \mathrm dx, $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int \frac{\arctan(\sin(2x))}{\cos^2x}dx,\    x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) 
>    $$

Now, I have no idea how to start . I checked wolframalpha and it gives an interesting solution ( I am not sure how it arrived there ) . Any hints will be appreciated !

Comment: Is $sin2x$ supposed to mean $\sin(2)x$ or $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin(2)x$ ?

Comment: @MaximillianJanisch Two of your options match.

Comment: Sorry for that ! I've edit it

Comment: Since when are the bounds of the definite integral denoted like that? Or it's an indefinite integral?

Comment: This is how it it in my textbook ... but i think this is an indefinite integral

Comment: Well, I think so too. Some more context would be helpful, like what's the name of the book or do the book atleast have answers for the exercises?

Comment: @Zacky is never far if there is an integral somewhere 

Comment: Well,   the thing  it is a Romanian book . ( I don't think it will help ) . Also, the book doesn't give an answer to this problem .

Comment: So, if we were to evaluate the indefinite integral, what will be the first step to do ?

Comment: I guess $x=\arctan t$ isn't bad since $\frac{dx}{\cos^2 x}= dt$ followed by integration by parts.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question right now. It will show only the indefinite integral . Sorry for not making it clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let tanx=t

$I= \int tan^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt$

using by parts $I= t.tan^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\int\frac{2(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2+4t^2}dt$

$I= t.tan^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\int\frac{2(\frac{1}{t^2}-1)}{(t+\frac{1}{t})^2+4}dt$

Now let $(t+\frac{1}{t})=z$

Comment: How did you reach to $ tan^{-1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2} $ ? (In the beginning )

Comment: substitution $tanx=t , sec^2xdx=dt$ and then $ arctan(sin2x)=arctan(\frac{2tanx}{1+tan^2x})$

Comment: Ok, thank you ! Now it is clear !

Comment: @Jon9 You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan\sin 2x}{\cos^2x}dx=0$ because the integrand is odd, and$$I:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan\sin 2x}{\cos^2x}dx=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\arctan\sin 2x}{\cos^2x}dx$$is finite. Indeed,$$\frac{I}{2}=[\tan x\cdot\arctan\sin 2x]_0^{\pi/4}-\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan x\cdot2\cos 2x dx}{1+\sin^22x}.$$Each term is finite; the integral is finite because $|\tan x|\le1$ on that range.

Edit, because it's been clarified an indefinite integral is sought: I'm not sure of a neat way to obtain [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan%28sin+2x%29%2F%28cos+x%29%5E2&dataset=) antiderivative (I'll have a think), but you can verify it by differeniation.

Comment: My sincere compliments. +1

Comment: I am sorry, I've  made a correction . It is actually an indefinite integral .

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{\arctan(\sin(2x))}{\cos^2x}dx$$
Let $u=\tan(x)$
$$I=\int\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 u}{u^2+1}\right)\,du$$ Integrate by parts
$$I=u\arctan\left(\dfrac{2u}{u^2+1}\right)+2\int\frac{ u \left(u^2-1\right)}{u^4+6 u^2+1}\,du$$
$$J=\int\frac{ u \left(u^2-1\right)}{u^4+6 u^2+1}\,du$$ $$\frac{ u \left(u^2-1\right)}{u^4+6 u^2+1}=\frac{u(u^2-1)}{\left(u^2+a\right) \left(u^2+b\right)}=\frac 1{a-b}\left(\frac{(a+1) u}{u^2+a}-\frac{(b+1) u}{u^2+b} \right)$$

$$J=\frac 1{2(a-b)}\left((a+1) \log \left(u^2+a\right)-(b+1) \log \left(u^2+b\right)\right)$$ Just finish if you want to go back to $x$ and have a nasty form.